# Why is MultiFieldQueryParser so much slower than creating query by hand?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.net to index a product catalog.  I was profiling my searches using ANTS Profiler and I noticed that the act of creating and parsing a query using the MultiFieldQueryParser took nearly as long as the actual search (approx 100ms).  I then tried creating the query manually, which happens very fast (approx 1ms).  I would rather not have to parse manually, although it does give me the same result set, I fear I might not be handling certain use cases or inputs (although the input is coming from a text search on a website and the users will no know anything about Lucene's search syntax).  My code (with both methods) is as follows:

```
        IApplicationSettings settings = new ApplicationSettingService();
        FSDirectory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(settings.GetSetting<string>("LuceneMainSearchDirectory")));
        RAMDirectory ramDir = new RAMDirectory(directory);
        _Searcher = new IndexSearcher(ramDir, true);        
        string[] searchFields = new string[] { "ProductName", "ProductLongDescription", "BrandName", "CategoryName" };

        //Add a wildcard character to end of search to give broader results 
        if (!searchTerm.EndsWith(" ")) { searchTerm = searchTerm + "*"; }


        //Use query parser...this  block typically takes about 100ms on my machine, roughly 40% on the constructor and 60% on the call to Parse
        MultiFieldQueryParser multiParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, searchFields, _analyzer);
        multiParser.SetDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
        Query query = multiParser.Parse(searchTerm);



        //Manually create query....this block doesn't even take 1ms on my machine
        BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery(true);
        var terms = searchTerm.Split(' ');
        foreach (string s in terms)
        {
            BooleanQuery subQuery = new BooleanQuery(true);
            if (!s.EndsWith("*"))
            {
                Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("ProductName", s));
                Query query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("ProductLongDescription", s));
                Query query3 = new TermQuery(new Term("BrandName", s));
                Query query4 = new TermQuery(new Term("CategoryName", s));
                subQuery.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
                subQuery.Add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
                subQuery.Add(query3, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
                subQuery.Add(query4, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
            }
            else
            {
                Query query1 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("ProductName", s));
                Query query2 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("ProductLongDescription", s));
                Query query3 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("BrandName", s));
                Query query4 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("CategoryName", s));
                subQuery.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
                subQuery.Add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
                subQuery.Add(query3, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
                subQuery.Add(query4, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
            }
            booleanQuery.Add(subQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        }


    //Run the search....results are the same for simple multiword text queries
        var result2 = _Searcher.Search(booleanQuery, null, maxResults);
        var result = _Searcher.Search(query, null, maxResults);
```

One option to save me using the manual query build might be to share the MultiFieldQueryParser, but I gather its Parse method is not threadsafe (although I only read that in relation to the java version...please correct me if I am wrong in that assumption).

Am I doing something wrong or is this just the nature of the beast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MultiFieldQueryParser` simply uses multiple regular QueryParsers under the scene, it creates one per field you want to query against.

It is normal that the creation of the `QueryParser` has a higher cost than simply creating the `Query` by hand.

It handles a complex query synthax documented here: [Apache Lucene - Query Parser Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_2/queryparsersyntax.html)

It will also process the search query using the `Analyzer` you specify. If you use an `Analyzer` at index time, you must use the same `Analyzer`/logic in your search code. If you don't you'll end up missing results.

If you used a Whitespace analyzer to index, then your code to manually build the BooleanQuery is fine.